# How to setup bootnode to use DNS address instead of IP4?

Tags: networking, nodes, network, https

I currently have a node running on the cloud and I've set its websocket port to a custom domain following Polkadot's Nginx config ([here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss)). I would like to be able to use this node as a bootnode for other nodes in the future. Ideally, I would like to use my custom domain instead of the node's IP. While following yet another Polkadot tutorial ([here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-setup-a-validator-with-reverse-proxy)) I modified my nginx configuration to the following:

```
server {

        server_name {CUSTOM_DOMAIN};

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
          proxy_buffering off;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:30333;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /ws {
          proxy_buffering off;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:9944;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.pem;

        ssl_session_cache shared:cache_nginx_SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";

}
```

I can successfully use my custom domain to access the WebSocket stuff, but when trying to use it for the p2p stuff it does not work.

I've tried setting the `--public-addr` parameter to my custom domain, running the bootnode like:

```
./path/to/binary --chain ./chainSpecRaw.json --base-path /tmp/node \
--ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --name "Bootnode 1" --pruning archive \
--public-addr="/dns/{CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/tcp/443/p2p/{PEER_ID}"
```

But when I try to run a new node as:

```
./target/release/contractuo-chain-node --chain ./chainSpecRaw.json --base-path /tmp/node \
    --name "Test Node" --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all \
    --bootnodes "/dns/{CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/tcp/443/p2p/{PEER_ID}"
```

It does not manage to find the bootnode. But if I swap the param to `--bootnodes "/ip4/{CLOUD_IP}/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/{PEER_ID}"` then it connects successfully.

Anyway, I don't know if I'm missing something on the nginx side, or on the node configuration, but I would like to be able to connect the nodes using my custom domain rather than the ip address.

Comment: What is your chainspec file? Did you edit this to include your bootnodes?

Comment: Sounds dumb: are you able to `dig {CUSTOM_DOMAIN}` from the node within this nginx instance? Perhaps DNS isn't working properly.

Comment: I am able to dig it and get a response. I do think that the problem is with the nginx config, but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your chain specification, best place being in the source itself, secondarily in the `plain` chain spec generated from that source, you can modify it and then convert it to `raw`. This is outlined in the [Custom Chain Specifications How-to Guide](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/basics/custom-chain-spec/).

Polkadot for example sets bootnodes in the [`node/service/res/polkadot.json` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/polkadot/master/node/service/res/polkadot.json):

```json
{
  "name": "Polkadot",
  "id": "polkadot",
  "chainType": "Live",
  "bootNodes": [
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-0.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWEPmjoRpDSUuiTjvyNDd8fejZ9eNWH5bE965nyBMDrB4o",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-1.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWLvcA24g6sT9YTaQyinwowMbLF5z7iMLoxZpEiV9pSmNf",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-2.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWDhp18HYzJuVX2jLhtjQgAhT1XWGqah42StoUJpkLvh2o",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-3.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWEsPEadSjLAPyxckqVJkp54aVdPuX3DD6a1FTL2y5cB9x",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-4.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWFfG1SQvcPoUK2N41cx7r52KYXKpRtZxfLZk8xtVzpp4d",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-5.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWDmQPkBvQGg9wjBdFThtWj3QCDVQyHJ1apfWrHvjwbYS8",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-6.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWBKtPpCnVTTzD7fPpCdFsrsYZ5K8fwmsLabb1JBuCycYs",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-7.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWP3BsFY6UaiLjEJ3YbDp6q6SMQgAHB15qKj41DUZQLMqD",
    "/dns/p2p.0.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWHsvEicXjWWraktbZ4MQBizuyADQtuEGr3NbDvtm5rFA5",
    "/dns/p2p.1.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWQz2q2UWVCiy9cFX1hHYEmhSKQB2hjEZCccScHLGUPjcc",
    "/dns/p2p.2.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWNHxjYbDLLbDNZ2tq1kXgif5MSiLTUWJKcDdedKu4KaG8",
    "/dns/p2p.3.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWGJQysxrQcSvUWWNw88RkqYvJhH3ZcDpWJ8zrXKhLP5Vr",
    "/dns/p2p.4.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWKer8bYqpYjwurVABu13mkELpX2X7mSpEicpjShLeg7D6",
    "/dns/p2p.5.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSRjL9LcEQd5u2fQTbyLxTEHq1tUFgQ6amXSp8Eu7TfKP",
    "/dns/cc1-0.parity.tech/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSz8r2WyCdsfWHgPyvD8GKQdJ1UAiRmrcrs8sQB3fe2KU",
    "/dns/cc1-1.parity.tech/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWFN2mhgpkJsDBuNuE5427AcDrsib8EoqGMZmkxWwx3Md4"
  ],
```

---

For reference,The source from How-to Guides

#### 1. Create a plain chain specification

Starting in the working directory of your node's working directory, and assuming the bin is `node-template`:

```bash
./target/release/node-template build-spec > chain-spec-plain.json
```

We have just generated a **plain chain spec** file for the *default* network set in your
`chain_spec.rs` file. This file can be passed to other nodes

#### 2. Modify the plain chain specification (optional)

This optional step we can leverage an *existing* plain chain specification for a network that otherwise would require modification of the *source* of the node to run on a *new network*.
For example, this can be quite useful in the [Cumulus Tutorial](/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay) where we want to create a custom *relay chain* without customizing Polkadot's source.

Here we use the *same* chain spec, but pass a flag to disable bootnodes, as we want a *new* network where these nodes will be different.

```bash
./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain chain-spec-plain.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > no-bootnodes-chain-spec-plain.json
```

This `no-bootnodes-chain-spec-plain.json` can be used to generate a SCALE storage encoded, distributable raw chain spec.

#### 3. Generate the raw chain specification

With a plain spec available, you generate a final raw chain spec by:

```bash
./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain chain-spec-plain.json --raw > chain-spec.json
```

#### 4. Publish the chain specification

> Note: Non-Determinism in Wasm & chain specs: Because Rust -> Wasm optimized builds aren't reproducible, each person will get a slightly different Wasm blob which will break consensus if each participant generates the file themselves. For the curious, learn more about this issue in [this blog post](https://dev.to/gnunicorn/hunting-down-a-non-determinism-bug-in-our-rust-wasm-build-4fk1).

It is *conventional* to include the chain specification files for your node *within the source code itself* so that anyone can build your node in the same way, whereby it becomes easy to check for non-determinism by comparing a genesis blob with another.
Polkadot, Kusama, Rococo, and more network chain spec files are found [in the source here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/service/res) along with a `.gitignore` file to ensure that you don't accidentally change these `!/*.json` files as you build further on your node's software and do [runtime upgrades](/tutorials/v3/forkless-upgrades).

#### 5. Start a new node

If you publish a node binary, or have users build their own and then they want to join your network, all then need is the *same* chain spec file and to run your binary with:

```bash
# binary named `node-template`
# `chain-spec.json` obtained from canonical common source
node-template --chain chain-spec.json
```

This can also simply be configured to be the *default* network.
For reference, you can see how [Polkadot implements](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/commits/master/cli/src/command.rs) a default command that uses the chain specs for various networks [in the source here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/service/res)

Comment: how is adding it to the chain spec different than passing it as a param when running the node?

Comment: The cli flag appends to the list, it doesn't replace it. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/cli/src/params/network_params.rs#L193-L194

Comment: But that's exactly my point, if it still adds it to the list then there's no difference. I tried it anyway, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might be that you are just missing `/wss`

So it should be `--bootnodes "/dns/{CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/tcp/443/wss/p2p/{PEER_ID}"`

Let us know if this solved your problem!

Comment: tried it both with and without, did not work. I managed to set up the reverse proxy with the IP but in a different port by using Nginx streams. but I could not find a way to set up the stream to use DNS.

Comment: Are there new errors or information that you can provide so we can get you a proper answer here? Definitely the examples you posted in your main question are missing the `/wss`, so maybe you need to post updated error messages with the proper commands

Comment: There aren't exactly error messages. The node just don't find each other. I believe the problem is that, using the DNS, the node can be found, but it replies through its own IP, and the connection can't be established because it should come from the same "origin". Not sure if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem comes from DNS but from archive mode.
We just faced the same problem with other nodes not syncing in archive mode, using `--validator` and removing `--pruning archive` solved the problem.
Not sure this is the expected behavior.

The difference is that in archive mode, the node will listen on `ws/p2p` URI while in collator mode it listens only on `p2p`.
But simply adding `ws` or `wss` into bootnode URI doesn't help reaching peers.

As per DNS config, you have a simpler alternative than proxy with nginx:

- Create a TXT record in DNS `_dnsaddr.{SUB_DOMAIN}` pointing to `"dnsaddr=/ip4/{BOOTNODE_IP}/tcp/30333/p2p/{PEER_ID}"`.
- Add `"/dnsaddr/{SUB_DOMAIN}/p2p/{PEER_ID}"` in chain specs.